# Does attourney client privilege protect communication with an employee?

Tags: immigration, attorney-client-privilege

I will be starting a new job in the US soon.  If I tell the company's immigration attorney a professionally embarrassing immigration issue I may face, are they likely to share this information with my new employer?

Comment: you are not the client in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The attorney in question is not *your* lawyer so attorney-client privilege does not apply.

Answer (score 4):

> If I tell the company's immigration attorney a professionally
>   embarrassing immigration issue I may face, are they likely to share
>   this information with my new employer?

Yes. That is because the attorney has a [fiduciary] duty toward its client (here, the company). Thus, he has the obligation to protect the company's interests or at least warn his client/employer about any risks your situation entails and which may result in (or be in preparation for) subsequent litigation.